# How to make it easy to select a database?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-external-storage

I am new to stack, but I figured I need help. I hope someone can help me :).

What I want to do is the following:

- the user of the App is saving some database (db3) files via PC in a folder he has to create. In my case he needs to call it "My Custom  Foler".
- implement a Spinner which lets the user choose from all db3 files of this directory  and then be able to do `db_selected.getReadableDatabase`

Just to put it in context: I am gonna implement a ContenProvider and the populate a `ListView` with Items from specific table using `SQliteOpenHelper` and `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. BUT THAT IS NOT MY QUESTION.

I want to setup this spinner. Maybe someone can help?

Here is my code so far with still a lot missing but the basic structure should be clear.

Greetings :)

> I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

> In activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list">

        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/select_database"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private final String DATABASE_PATH = "My Custom Folder";

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //either we show login page or the populated ListView
            ListView populatedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            View logInView = findViewById(R.id.login_view);
            populatedListView.setEmptyView(logInView);

            //How to setup a Spinner which lets select a ".db3" from a custom created Folder
            Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.select_database);
            //When Spinner item is clicked/touched I am gonna load it into my ListView
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: spinner example https://www.javatpoint.com/android-spinner-example this may helps you

Comment: this only explains a general spinner setup. I want to know how can I read, and then select a database from a primary external storage. Basically in a custom created directory called "My Custom Folder". From all databases I want to get the name as String and display it in the spinner.